# Showing that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}k^2=\frac{n^3}{4n-2}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

As mentioned in the title, I want to prove (in the simplest way) that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}k^2=\frac{n^3}{4n-2}$$

I don't really know how to proceed, my guess would be to use polynomials like
$$
\left(1+x\right)^{2n}=\left(1+x\right)^n\left(1+x\right)^n
$$
and differentiate to make the $k^2$ appear but I'm not convinced, the only thing i can prove is that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}
$$
and I wonder if there exists simple way of proving such an equality.

Comment: hint $$k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Thank you, I thought you were a Metamorphosis professor but you are so versatile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go ahead $$S'=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left[k {n \choose k}\right]^2=n^2\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n-1 \choose k-1}^2=\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose p}^2=n^2{2(n-1)\choose n-1} $$ $$S=\frac{S'}{{2n \choose n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}k^2=n^2\frac{{2(n-1)\choose n-1}}{{2n \choose n}}
=\frac{n^3}{4n-2}.$$